# Powershell curl calls fails on the second request

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I am creating a script to call a couple of endpoints in my service.
The calls look like this:

```
$scheduleResponse=(curl -Method 'POST' -Uri $baseUrl'/scheduletests' `
            -Headers @{"Accept"="application/json";"Content-Type"="application/json"} `
            -Body $body)
$scheduleContent=ConvertFrom-Json([String]::new($scheduleResponse.Content))
#Error checks here
$testId = [String]::new($scheduleContent.ScheduleTests.TestID)
$getTestResultsBody = '{"TestID":"' + $testId + '"}' #Hard-coding this value works.
$getResponse=(curl -Method 'POST' -Uri $baseUrl'/gettestresults' -Headers @{"Accept"="application/json";"Content-Type"="application/json"} -Body $getTestResultsBody)
```

My getResponse fails with this error message:

> curl : Unable to read data from the transport connection: The
> connection was closed. At C:\Development\Services\TESTService\Test
> Clients\Caller.ps1:43 char:27  ... etResponse=(curl -Method 'POST'
> -Uri $baseUrl'/gettestresults' -Heade ...
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], IOException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

I debugged my service and it is receiving the correct request and sending the correct response back.
If I hard-code testId in the getRequest, the whole script works. So my guess is that it has something to do with reading the test id from the first call.
Any pointers on what could be wrong?

Comment: What happens if you -join the static string and $testId to a new variable and use this new variable in place of the existing additive string construction?

    `$test=(-join("TestID:'",$testId,"'"))`

    `$getTestResultsBody = '{$test}'`

Comment: Same result unfortunately.

Comment: What is the hard-coded value when it works? And what is the value of ```$testId``` when it fails? The way you’re building the body text, if $testId has any special characters in it (e.g quotes or line breaks) it’s going to generate invalid json. You might be better building a hashtable and using ```convertto-json``` instead...